# Not reading all the data from boost::asio socket

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm trying tp fetch a list of emails over IMAP using boost::asio socket synchronously. My implementation is

```
std::string cmail::ImapClient::execute(const std::string &cmd)
{
    boost::system::error_code error;
    boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(cmd), error);
    if(error)
    {
        spdlog::error("Failed to dispatch command " + cmd + " because " + error.message());
        return ""; 
    }

    boost::asio::streambuf buffer;
    boost::asio::read_until(socket, buffer, '\n', error);
    if(error)
    {
        spdlog::error("Failed to receive response for command " + cmd + " because " + error.message());
        return "";
    }

    boost::asio::streambuf::const_buffers_type data = buffer.data();
    std::string response(boost::asio::buffers_begin(data), boost::asio::buffers_begin(data) + buffer.size());
    if(spdlog::default_logger()->level() == spdlog::level::trace)
    {
        std::string s = response;
        s.pop_back();
        spdlog::trace("S: " + s);
    }

    return response;
}
```

The actual `cmd` I'm passing this method is `A002 FETCH 1:* (BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (DATE FROM SUBJECT)] FLAGS)`. There are 5 emails in the inbox. So `1.*` should fetch 5 emails. However, I only get the full email information for email 1 and 2 and just the "From" field of the 3rd email.

If I change the command to `A002 FETCH 2:5 (BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (DATE FROM SUBJECT)] FLAGS)`, again I get the expected content for emails 2 and 3 while the `response` doesn't contain anything after the "From" field of the 4th.

EDIT:

I verify that there are 5 mails in the inbox by issuing the command `A001 SEARCH SINCE 10-Apr-2020` to which the server responds with `* SEARCH 1 2 3 4 5`.

As to how I verify that server responded with data for 5 emails, according to the protocol spec, the server should finish the response of with `A002 OK ...`, `A002 NO ...` or `A002 BAD ...`. The response I get does not send this terminating clause. Also, in both case which looks like the payload is geting truncated the size of response is 512 characters. Not sure how rigorous this verification is but the number of bytes at 512 seems to point at some size limit somewhere...

Comment: According to `boost::asio::read_until` docs, the shown code reads whatever's received on the socket until the first time the delimiter, which in this case is `\n`, is received. I'm not sure I understand how the above code is expected to read a metric crapton of lines of text in an IMAP response that contains multiple E-mails. And, in general, you can't parse this way. IMAP format is too complicated to be dealt with by such simplistic attempt to parse it. Having written an IMAP server, and a client, myself, I do not see how the above can deal with all requirements of IMAP structured responses.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  I added edits answering your previous query which I think also points to a more specific issue pertaining to reading the data from socket. Not sure if the "simplistic" approach is the cause of this issue. IMAP is a line-based protocal. So, do you see something specifically wrong with this approach for the specific query I'm making? Thanks.

Comment: No, IMAP is not simply a line-based protocol. It mixes individual lines together with byte-counted strings. See the formal specification for a literal string in section 4.3 of RFC 3501, for one such example. Yes, I see something specifically wrong, which I believe I explained fully in my previous comment. You can't expect to correctly handle IMAP responses this way. IMAP has to be parsed using a lexical analyzer, that parses each individual token, one token at a time. A newline is simply one of such tokens. This has nothing to do with boost. The overall logic is flawed.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  I see, understand now. Thanks very much for the clarification. Will work on the parser then. I thought I was missing something in boost socket.